# How do I make a HTML or URL compatable for mobile phones

Tags: javascript, encoding, hyperlink, urlencode, jscript

I have just created an HTML or URL link for multiple URLs, however, it is not compatible with mobile phones. Is there any coding that I can put into the HTML to make it compatible?

Comment: You should Google mobile-friendly HTML and responsive web designs.

Comment: Did you create an html page, or a link to it? Multiple links to the same page? Multiple pages with multiple links? Which aspect wasn't compatible? HTML can be made to be compatible, but how to make specific html compatible requires it to be shown. Please add more details to this question, and clarify the aspects which are overly vague.

Comment: it's really difficult because I don't know the terminology for this kind of stuff. I created one link, which directs you to 6 different links at random each time you click it. This works on desktops/laptops, but when I try to click the link on my phone it says it cannot take me to that link

Comment: Can you show the code you used to make the link? It is possible that mobile browsers prevent multiple tabs from being opened, if you meant by 6 different links at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can add media queries to your CSS to add the responsiveness. If you're not comfortable with it, then you can also try to add *bootstrap* library to your project and use it. They have good documentation on how to make your website responsive and fluid in nature.

Link : https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries, 
 example

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .p{color: red;}
}
```

if the screen is larger than 767px the text won't be red

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206113/discussion-on-answer-by-giuppox-how-do-i-make-a-html-or-url-compatable-for-mobil).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Link</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var links = [
          "http://google.com/",
          "http://stackoverflow.com/",
          "http://amazon.com/"
            ];
        $(".myLink").attr("href",links[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)])
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="myLink" href="#">
      Click me to go to a random webpage
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do i put this coding into jquery??

Comment: no, on your pc, create a file named name.html. print this code in. And you have your webpage file

Comment: to view it open it with the browser

Comment: if you are using a mac, right click > open with > yourBrowser